# Proving My Coroutines Work

Tags: c#, mono, coroutine, proof

I just wrote a coroutine (as an exercise) implementation based on Mono Continuations (very weird experience). What are some ways / approaches that I should take to prove its correctness?

Comment: Start by listing the desired postconditions of every operation in your program given the preconditions. Define a system of rules of logical inference. Then provide a proof in that system that in your program, every postcondition is a logical consequence of the given precondition. How else would you do a formal proof of correctness?